# The application does not see the bluetooth device normally on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I display a list of bluetooth devices in the console in the vicinity, but it displays almost everything without a name, only one phone displays the name. If look through the bluetooth settings in the phone, then everything is displayed normally with names. What could be the problem? Using the flutter_blue_plus package.
He also does not see the device I need, although everything is also visible through the settings.

```
scanSubScription = flutterBlue.scan().listen((scanResult) {
  print('------');
  print("${scanResult.device.name} --- ${scanResult.rssi}");
  print(scanResult.device);
  if (scanResult.device.name == TARGET_DEVICE_NAME) {
    print('DEVICE found');
    stopScan();
    setState(() {
      connectionText = "Found Target Device";
    });

    targetDevice = scanResult.device;
    connectToDevice();
  }
}, onDone: () => stopScan());
```

This is my scan code

Here is the output in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may happen due to not having location permission. For Android you need these permissions:

```
<!-- Tell Google Play Store that your app uses Bluetooth LE
     Set android:required="true" if bluetooth is necessary -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

<!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Full details on [PubDev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)